# Is it possible for someone to do their masters in Maths once they've earned their degree in Computer Science?

Tags: changing-fields

I was wondering. Is it possible for someone to major in Maths as in do their masters in Maths once they've earned their degree in Computer Science?

Comment: This particular stackexchange site is about the computer software Wolfram Mathematica.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. I know several people who have switched their graduate degrees, e.g. Math -> Computer Science, Biology -> Chemical Engineering, etc. You might have to take some extra classes, though.